# & vs && in query in RavenDb

Tags: c#, .net, ravendb

Im new at RavenDb, and maybe there is a perfect reason for this behavior.

the expression below gives me a different (and correct) result:

```
var elements = session
.Query<Elements_ByParameterValueAndName.Result, Elements_ByParameterValueAndName>()
.Where(x=>x.ParameterName=="Name"&&x.ParameterValue.StartsWith("VÄNT"))                   
.OfType<DbElement>()
.ToList();
```

and this does not:

```
var elements = session
.Query<Elements_ByParameterValueAndName.Result, Elements_ByParameterValueAndName>()
.Where(x=>x.ParameterName=="Name"&x.ParameterValue.StartsWith("VÄNT"))                   
.OfType<DbElement>()
.ToList();
```

The difference is the double ampersand in the where clause.
Is this expected behavior? I know that the single & should not matter in this situation and that I "always" should use double &&. But it's scary because the correct element count was 25 and the actual was 128 (max value)

Any ideas?

Comment: im not sure what you are asking but difference is obvious. `&&` will not evaluate right side when left side of expression is false. but `&` does evaluate both. edit: anyway i dont think this makes any difference here.

Comment: Exactly, I know what the difference between && and &.
I just dont understand how it can produce different results in this case. 
Its like & gives me all of the avaliable documents.

Comment: I'm guessing RavenDB does not support bitwise operators. Can you inspect the actual query that is generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RavenDB does not support bitwise comparisons. It will always evaluate both sides on the server side.

Comment: Ok, but then how do you explain the behavior? 
It seems like when its fed with a single & the return is Always true.

Comment: Because & is not used in queries, and isn't supported by the linq provider.